The post filtering in child-category does not work
The post filtering in child-category does not work in Wordpress
/category/child-category-1/filter_xxx-yyy/  - WORK
/category/child-category-1/child-category-2/filter_xxx-yyy/ - NOT work
/category/child-category-1/child-category-2/child-category-3/filter_xxx-yyy/ - NOT work
        add_action('pre_get_posts', array($this, 'filter_posts_by_custom_fields'));
        add_action('init', array($this, 'register_rewrite_rules'));
        
    public function register_rewrite_rules() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^category/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&custom_filter=$matches[2]', 'top');
        add_rewrite_tag('%custom_filter%', '([^&]+)');
    }

public function filter_posts_by_custom_fields($query) { 
    if (!$query->is_main_query() || !is_category() || !$query->get('custom_filter')) return;

    $custom_filter = $query->get('custom_filter');
    $filters = explode('-and-', $custom_filter);

    $meta_query = ['relation' => 'AND'];
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        if (strpos($filter, 'filter_') === 0) {
            list($key, $value) = explode('-', $filter, 2);

            $values = explode('-plus-', $value);

            $meta_query[] = [
                'key' => $key,
                'value' => count($values) > 1 ? $values : $value,
                'compare' => count($values) > 1 ? 'IN' : '='
            ];
        }
    }
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
}

How can I make the filter work at all levels of categories?
Sorry for My English.

The rule ^category/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ can be interpreted "a URL that starts with the literal text category, followed by one or more characters that are not forward slashes, followed by something. So that is basically three things, and that matches your first test. Your subsequent tests have four and five things. Mostly likely everything after the second things is being jammed into the last thing, which means that custom_filter has child-category-2/child-category-3/filter_xxx-yyy/  in the last scenario.

Your best bet is to write individual rules for whatever depth you ultimately want to support. If it is the tests provided, two more rules adding ([^/]+) inside for each depth. I'm not certain what the mapping the query would be, however.
